# html2canvas - Canvas is pushed/cropped/cut

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, html2canvas

My canvas export is cut/moved/cropped.
Seems like my element is pushed to the left so I can see the background of the canvas.
My element has white color.

I tried to resolve the problem with `{x: 0, y: 0}` but then element which I want to convert to canvas is pushed to the middle of the canvas, so I can see the background color of canvas again.
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/kdbh0m

Screenshots: http://prntscr.com/kdb944, http://prntscr.com/kdb9fg

How it should look: http://prntscr.com/kdbbjl

1st screenshot code:

`<canvas width="270" height="480" style="width: 1080px; height: 1920px;"></canvas>`

2nd screenshot code:

`<canvas width="270" height="480" style="width: 1080px; height: 1920px;"></canvas>`

Implementation code:

```
html2canvas(template, {
  useCORS: true,
  widht: 1080,
  height: 1920,
  backgroundColor: "red" // color of the canvas. Added for test
  }).then(canvas => {
      html2canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);
  });
```

I noticed that this problem is repeated more often on Heroku then on localhost but I'm not sure if that is the problem. As I saw in the docs html2canvas is not dependent of the backend.

- html2canvas version tested with: 1.0.0-alpha.12
- Browser & version: Google Chrome
- Operating system: Windows 10
- Front-end framework: VueJS v2.5.2